# Pool (the game) site proposal

Tags: discussion, area51, se-sites

I was thinking of proposing a SE site about pool (the game). I saw we already have a [pool](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pool) here, which isn’t the most popular.

Topics could include:

- Rules
- Cues
- The online 8 ball pool game
- Tournaments
- Breaks
- Tactics
- Spins
- 9 ball pool

In my opinion, this could do as a separate SE site, what does everyone else think? Would anyone be interested in this proposal?

I have contacted the makers of the 8 ball pool app and online game for a possible advertisement or sponsorship.

Comment: The Area51 FAQ are pretty much against this idea. Also why not just promote/establish it here?

Comment: @dly I think there is a big enough community for it

Comment: In 9 years, Sports SE has had 51 questions tagged [tag:pool] that aren't closed. That's less than one every two months. The number of questions for all billiards-class sport tags brings the total to perhaps one per month. *Where is this "big enough community for it"?* Unless you have a specific, active, existing community numbering in the hundreds who need a focused Q&A site and have identified SE as an appropriate venue to focus on, this proposal will absolutely fail. If it were even permitted, because you haven't demonstrated at all that the topic is insufficiently served here. @Daniil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with dly and Nij here - there isn't enough interest in pool to justify a separate site. I'd rather see an effort to drive people to this site than splitting the content across two sites.

That doesn't mean you can't propose it on Area 51, but my *personal* view is that it would be likely to fail.

Comment: Ok, I'll add to the existing pool database here with some Q and A's

Comment: Excellent idea. Please remember that we [support people answering their own question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).